# Add (true || ... ) to a function using sed

Tags: shell, sed, gnu

I quickly want to patch a huge library by adding `true ||` in front of every function call.

Example input:

```
if function_a(some_parameters) && function_b
```

would turn into

```
if (true || function_a(some_parameters)) && function_b
```

The problem is that just prepending `true ||`  disables the entire statement. Therefore I have to add parenthesis arround the function call.

The parameters are different every time.

Is this possible with GNU sed?

Comment: What language is that? Do you want to prepend `true ||` to `function_b` in the statement, too?

Comment: Do you need to handle parameter lists with newlines? Why can't you instead edit `function_a` to make it a no-op?

Comment: 1st: `function_b` is any function / anything that follows the invocation of 'function_a'. And I don't want to prepend true || to it

Comment: 2nd: I can't make `function_a` a non-op as it is part of another library.

Comment: why don't you simply change `if function_a(some_parameters) && function_b` to this ........... `if my_no-op_function_a(some_parameters) && function_b`?

Comment: OK, I kinda feel dumb now. Now my question would be "How to replace a function call with true". EDIT: instead of creating a new function I'd prefer changing the entire function invocation to `true`

Comment: Perhaps you can try : sed 's/^.*&& //'

Comment: @ctac_ as this removes the entire function call, a line like `return unless function_a()` would end up as a syntax error.

Comment: I ended up using `sed 's/function_a([^()]*)/true/'`. Hope that there are no stacked functions in `function_a` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having received some feedback in the comments, I ended up using

```
sed 's/function_a([^()]*)/true/'
```

This command replaces every instance of `function_a (some_optional_parameters)` with true.

It worked because there were no nested functions in the parameters of `function_a.` Please note that this will not work for every programming language / for programs with nested functions.

Comment: This is something you might want to consider doing in your IDE.

Comment: I wanted to integrate this line into a shell script that automatically patches the library after download. I tried using my IDE (GNOME Builder), to be quite honest, but in the end I still needed a shell script to automatically run inside a container.